# Paraphrase the sentence "I didn't know how expensive the desk was!"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Please take a look at the following sentence:

> I didn't know how expensive the desk was!

This sentence means that the desk is very expensive, but the speaker didn't realize it then. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are right!

Your assumption is true for one good reason - *the exclamation mark!* This mark is used for ['surprise'](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-exclamation-mark.htm) here. This shows that the speaker is surprised looking at the price of the desk. He did not expect the price to be *that* high.